# Highcharts crosshair label is behind legend

Tags: javascript, svg, legend, highcharts

When crosshair label gets too long, it reaches the legend. And legend is over the crosshair label, because it comes later in the code of Highcharts svg. 
`xAxis.crosshair.zIndex` doesn't effect it at all.
Any idea how to make it come foward?

[image]

Here is the example of the code: http://jsfiddle.net/oeuakvva/4/

```
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
    legend: {
        enabled: true,
        borderColor: 'black',
        borderWidth: 2
    },
    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'ADBE',
        data: ADBE
    }, {
        name: 'MSFT',
        data: MSFT
    }],
    tooltip: {
      enabled: false
    },
    xAxis: {
      crosshair: {
        label: {
          enabled: true,
          formatter: function(){
            return "ddd<br>lllllll<br>oooooooo<br>wwwwwwww<br>vvvvvvvvvv<br>lllllll<br>oooooooo<br>wwwwwwww<br>vvvvvvvvvv";
          }
        }
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: where is code?? update your post with the code you are using

Comment: Added the code and you can see how many elements come in front of the crosshair label. How to make it in front of all?

Comment: This looks relevant: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/759

Comment: Thank you, it is relevant but provides no solution for this issue, as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move up the legend in the svg tree after the chart is loaded:

```
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
  chart: {
    events: {
      load () {
        this.legend.group.attr({
          zIndex: -99
        })
      }
    }
  },
```

In some cases it might be needed to do this also after [chart's redraw](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.redraw).

live example: http://jsfiddle.net/d6k8yd8g/

Comment: Thank you, it's a great tip! How to make it for all other elements that come over the hairline? In the navigator there are lines and numbers that come over (in you move the mouse to the very right point, you'll see it). Is it possible to do something like `this.hairlineLabel.group.attr({ zIndex: 199 })` and move it at the end of the svg ?

Comment: Yes, you can adjust the zIndex of any group - you might need to experiment with the value to not loose other features, e.g. events. http://jsfiddle.net/xLpo3af3/1/